# JS looping issue

Tags: javascript

I have I guess a simple javascript question, 
but I do not know how to do it 
here is my script:

```
var datasetValue = [];
var count = 3;
for (var j=0; j<count; j++) {
    datasetValue[j] = {
        fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
        strokeColor :'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        title :'2013',
        data : [Math.round(Math.random() * 100),Math.round(Math.random() * 100)-10]
    };
}

var mydata = {
    datasets : datasetValue
};

alert("Datasets: mydata.datasets[0].data);
```

So the output here will be two random number
However what I would like the output to look like is :

```
datasets: [{
            fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
            strokeColor :'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            title :'2013',
            data : 35,25,
           },
           {
           fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
            strokeColor :'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            title :'2013',
            data : 12,02,
           },
           fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
            strokeColor :'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            title :'2013',
            data : 38,28,
           },
           }];
```

In other words I would like the output to be the datasetValue base on the count value;

Could someone give me a hand on that ?

Comment: Please don't tag Javascript questions with the Java tag. They are entirely different languages

Comment: It seems the data in `dataset` object is like the one you've written on your post, so what's the problem?

Comment: `var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 90)` and `{ ..., data : [r+10, r] }`

Comment: You need to change yout for loop to for (var j=0; j<=count; j++) and the alert should be ("Datasets:"+mydata.datasets[0].data);

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Hi thx for your answers, maybe my post wasn't clear enough and I am sorry for that ; I am using charts.Js to create dynamic charts. What I am trying to achieve is to have dynamic datasets, which means that for count = 3, to get an output like the one showed in my post rendering fillColor, strokeColor, title and data 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through three entries you need to change your comparison operator to less than or equal to `<=`

```js
var datasetValue = [];
var count = 2;
for (var j=0; j<=count; j++) {
    datasetValue[j] = {
        fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
        strokeColor :'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        title :'2013',
        data : [Math.round(Math.random() * 100),Math.round(Math.random() * 100)-10]
    };
}

var mydata = {
    datasets : datasetValue
};

document.write(JSON.stringify(datasetValue));

alert("Datasets: "+mydata.datasets[0].data);
```

Comment: Hi iSZ, thanks for your answer, is it possible to not transform it into a json format but more into an array ? chart.JS does not accept strings

Comment: @Ben2pop At the moment the datasetValue is an array of objects, the JSON.stringify() is just there so I could print out an example to show you that is similar to the output you required. You should be able to use the variable in a chart js dataset like datasets: datasetValue if that's your intention.

Comment: ok great you are right, can I ask a last question to undertstand ? 
I created a random color var random_color = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')'; that put into they array as backgroundColor: random_color, however it is awlays the same color that is outputed how can I make a different color at each iteration?

Comment: That should be fine, just make sure you run the line inside the loop so its running more than once

Answer (score 0):

I hope understand what you mean!

change: `datasetValue[j] = { ... }`

with this one: `datasetValue.push({...});`

Comment: Wouldn't this accomplish the same thing since the iterator starts at 0 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

i think below code is enough to understated

```
var commonData =  {
        fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
        strokeColor :'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
        title :'2013'
      }
var datasetValue = [];
var count = 2;
for (var j=0; j<count; j++) {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
    commonData.data = [rand, rand-10]
    datasetValue.push(commonData)
  }

var mydata = {
    datasets : datasetValue
};
alert("Datasets:"+ JSON.stringify(mydata.datasets[0].data));
// or use console.log , is better debugging 
console.log("Datasets:",mydata.datasets[0].data )
```